# WPF ToolKit Datagrid refresh binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, wpftoolkit

On my datagrid I've got a DataTrigger determining which colour to set the foreground (Text) to be. This value is being stored as a property of my page.

I've got this all working nicely but now I'm giving the user the functionality to set this colour themselves.

My problem is when this colour is set by the user and I update the property how do I make the datagrid now reflect this change.

Example of what I am doing below (PrivateMessages being show in different colour)

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsPrivate}" Value="True">                                    
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ElementName=GridPage, Path=PrivateMessageColour}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Any help or guidance would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your type implements the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface and you fire the change notification on the setter of your publicly exposed property which the `DataTrigger` is bound to when you modify the color.

**EDIT**: Below is an example using a `TextBox` and a `Button` to change the color...

C#:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    MyData _data = new MyData();

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = _data;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _data.ChangeColor();
    }
}

    public class MyData : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Random _rand = new Random();
        List<String> _colors = new List<string> { "Red", "Black", "Blue" };

        public void ChangeColor()
        {
            MyColor = _colors[_rand.Next(0, 3)];
        }

        private bool _isActive = true;
        public bool IsActive
        {
            get
            {
                return _isActive;
            }
            set
            {
                _isActive = value;
                PropertyChangedEventHandler h = PropertyChanged;
                if (h != null)
                    h(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsActive"));
            }
        }


        private String _myColor = "Green";
        public String MyColor
        {
            get
            {
                return _myColor;
            }
            set
            {
                _myColor = value;
                PropertyChangedEventHandler h = PropertyChanged;
                if (h != null)
                    h(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyColor"));
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
    <Grid>
        <Button Height="25" Click="Button_Click" Content="Change Color" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        <TextBox Width="200" Height="100">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="{Binding MyColor}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for this the collection the datatrigger is working off implements INotifyPropertyChanged it the setter I'm having issues with, would this benefit from having the property use this also?

Comment: @Emlyn Based on your code you posted the IsPrivate property is the source property which would need to fire the PropertyChanged event notification.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I feel I'm starting to wander off the path. I just need someway perhaps to cause the grid to check which colour the text should be displayed in and repaint itself if this has changed. Will have a look to see if their is a better way of implementing these triggers as I get the feeling that perhaps I need a event trigger also.

Comment: @Emlyn Added fully functional sample using a TextBox and a Button to change the color; you should be able to adapt to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for this example, I'm not sure I've made myself clear. This "Private message Colour" property is separate to my collection of messages and is just a property on my wpf window. If I get chance I'll cut down my project and see if I can post an example on here. Thanks once again for all your input.

Comment: @Emlyn It doesn't matter where the data is coming from the concepts are the same.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I've now got it working. Added the INotifyPropertyChange to my Window and it sprung to life.